# Layout error - Inflating class <unknown

Tags: android, layout, layout-inflater

I have an error in my layout main.xml :
android.view.InflateException : Binary XML file line #406 : Error inflating class

My application run on S4 4.4.2 but failed on 5.0.2

drawable-mdpi/loupe.png => 31*32 px
I've just one loupe.png picture in my drawables.

The size of the image is correct and the place in the RelativeLayout too.

**main.xml :**
Line 406 : the last "ImageView"

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >
  ...
  <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/cancel_search"
        android:src="@drawable/annuler"
        android:layout_width="65dip"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="75dip"
  android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/main_title"
  />
   
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_field"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="35dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/main_title"
  android:background="@drawable/recherche"
  android:focusable="false"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
  android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
  android:hint="@string/rechercher"
  android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loupe"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/search_field"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/search_field"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/loupe" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: for example, If You have a large image on imageView, it could also happen that it could not be inflated....how big is Your image?

Comment: Hi Opiatefuchs, i see on my logcat this line : Caused by : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : Failed to allocate a 238092 byte allocation with 55476 free bytes and 54kb until 00M.

Comment: That´s what I mean... You must be thrifty with the resources. To make this better, keep the images You use as small as possible (byte and size in pixels) and use the different drawable folders for different devices, such as drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi etc...